# Extending / Reimplementing Applications

Tags: android, android-contacts, android-source, contactscontract

Ultimately I wish to produce a compressive Contact Manager with some specific features.
I thought it would be good to experiment by extending [Contact](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Contacts.git;a=summary).
So using git I checked out froyo-release and tried to build it.
That didn't work so well as it contains things like

> import
>   com.android.internal.telephony.CallerInfo;

and friends.
I'm considering the following two approaches:

1. Suppress the internal stuff under
   the assumption that I really don't
   need it.
2. Start with a toy Contact Manager 
   and implement (reinvent) everything.

My guess is that I am going about this incorrectly.
"I want that third alternative" --kirk.

Just for completeness, the new special behavior is to provide
an action list for a contact based on the types of that entities data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of the applications that ship with the platform unfortunately make use of non-public api's, which means they require a lot of hacking to build as sdk apps.

You can build them as part of a full platform build, or you can modify them to connect to the private api's via reflection or by including stubs for the private api functions that will get automatically stripped out later (as their names conflict with the real ones) - but if you want the result of your work to be something you can portably and reliably distribute other than as part of a rom upgrade, you probably need to rework things to use only public APIs.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like reworking to use public API's then.  Any advice on how to proceed with that?

Comment: Probably first identify what all of the build errors are, then for each one go looking if there's comparable functionality that's been added to the public APIs since the platform app was first written, or if there's structurally different alternative approach to doing it - or if you've run up against something that just can't be accomplished by a properly behaved SDK app at present.